# Jmeter Jenkins java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Jenkins Jmeter performance trend plugin parses .jtl file successfully but shows the following error with exception while parsing a .log file:

> ```
>  Performance: Recording JMeter reports '**/*.jtl'
>  Performance: Parsing JMeter report file SIP_#61.jtl
>  Performance: Parsing JMeter report file SIP_#62.jtl
>  Performance: File SIP_#61.jtl reported 0.0% of errors [SUCCESS]. Build status is: SUCCESS
>  Performance: File SIP_#62.jtl reported 0.0% of errors [SUCCESS]. Build status is: SUCCESS
>  Performance: Recording JmeterSummarizer reports '**/*.log'
>  Performance: Parsing JMeterSummarizer report file SIP_#61.log
>  ERROR: Build step failed with exception
>  java.util.InputMismatchException
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2265)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2225)
> at hudson.plugins.performance.JmeterSummarizerParser.parse(JmeterSummarizerParser.java:82)
> at hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.perform(PerformancePublisher.java:222)
> at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
> at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
> at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
> at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
> Build step 'Publish Performance test result report' marked build as failure
> Finished: FAILURE
> ```

Comment: even if your log file contains some weird data, no reason for the plug-in to fail with such exception. I would report the bug to plug-in developers.

Comment: Is this the infamous Jenkins Performance plugin? The one that is no longer maintained?

Comment: @automaictester- YES. Is there any Jenkins plugin or method for Jmeter to display performance trend ?